# Quick Action using Visualforce - close modal function

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, quickaction

According to [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_closeQuickAction.htm), `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();` should be used for closing modal window when using Lightning Component as Quick Action. Is there documented analog of this action that can be used for Visualforce used as Quick Action?

I can see in some forums/posts `Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name: "publisher.close", payload: {refresh:"true"}});` but I'm not sure if it's something documented/recommended by Salesforce.

Is the approach above documented/recommended by Salesforce for closing Visualforce Quick Action modals? If not, is there a "best practice" method to achieve this currently for Visualforce?